# output of a callback as input of another callback, second callback run twice

Tags: plotly-dash

The dashboard include a dropdown, a table and a graph.
By selecting a item from dropdown, some rows of the table is shown and figure plot the data in the table.
I have two callback,

```
at the first one:
input : dropdown
output: table
```

```
second one:
input: table
output: figure
```

So the output of first callback is input of the second one.

The following code output look like this:
[image]

```py
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
from copy import deepcopy
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


data = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["a1", "a2"],
                     "b": [1, 2]})

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
    prevent_initial_callbacks=True,
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(dbc.Col([dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown1',
            options=[
                {'label': '1', 'value': 1},
                {'label': '2', 'value': 2}
            ],
            value=1)])),
        dbc.Row(
            dbc.Col([
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id="datatable",
                    columns=[dict(id=i,
                                  name=j,
                                  )
                             for i, j in zip(
                        ["a", "b"],
                        ["a", "b"],
                    )],
                    data=data.loc[data['a'] ==
                                  "a1"].to_dict("records"),
                    sort_mode="single",
                )
            ])),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col([html.Div(
            children=dcc.Graph(id="graph"), className="card")
        ])]),
    ], fluid=True,
)
########################################################


@app.callback(
    Output("datatable", "data"),
    [Input("dropdown1", "value")],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_current_table(value):

    idx = int(value)
    print(idx)

    if idx == 1:
        df = (data.loc[data["a"] == "a1"])
        return df.to_dict("records")
    else:
        df = deepcopy(data.loc[data["a"] == "a2"])
        return df.to_dict("records")
########################################################


@ app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input("datatable", "derived_virtual_data"),
     Input("dropdown1", "value")
     ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_figure(table, value):

    df = pd.DataFrame(table)
    print(df)

    fig = go.Figure()
    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8000)
```

The problem here is callback run twice:

```sh
    a  b
0  a1  1
    a  b
0  a2  2
```

and for the first time print the previous values of the table
This cause error in the main code that I am working on.

How to prevent dash from runnig callback twice?

I found some other questions complaining about running the callback twic, but I could not found a proper solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two inputs for the callback that's running twice:

```py
@ app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input("datatable", "derived_virtual_data"),
     Input("dropdown1", "value")
     ],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_figure(table, value):
```

The dropdown changes, and triggers this callback, but it also triggers the table to update. The updated table causes the `derived_virtual_data`to trigger this callback again. You can fix this by making the dropdown value a `State` instead, like this:

```py
@ app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input("datatable", "derived_virtual_data")],
    [State("dropdown1", "value"),]
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_figure(table, value):
```

Edit:
On another read through, you don't even use the `value` from the dropdown in the second input. Just removing it entirely will also work:

```py
@ app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input("datatable", "derived_virtual_data")],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_figure(table):
```